# How to fetch JSON Data

Tags: android, android-json

Here is the JSON file that I need to fetch data from:

```
{}JSON
     []Learning Standards
       {}0
        {}Learning Standards
          * standard_title : Sample_1
          * ref_id : TSB_01
          * description :  This is a sample JSON Format
        {}1
         {}Learning Standards
          * standard_title : Sample_2
          * ref_id : TSB_02
          * description :  This is a sample JSON Format
         {}2
          {}Learning Standards
          * standard_title : Sample_3
          * ref_id : TSB_03
          * description :  This is a sample JSON Format

          {}3
           {}4
             {}5
               {}6
```

My code is as follows,

```
// JSON file URL address 
jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("54.152.108.131/iphone111/getLearningStandards");
try {
    // Locate the NodeList name 
    jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("LearningStandards");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
        jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
        WorldPopulation worldpop = new WorldPopulation();
        worldpop.setRank(jsonobject.optString("standard_title"));
        worldpop.setCountry(jsonobject.optString("ref_id"));
        worldpop.setPopulation(jsonobject.optString("description"));
    }
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: show code what you have tried?

Comment: I don't understand how this format is a json?

Comment: // JSON file URL address
   jsonobject = JSONfunctions
     .getJSONfromURL("http://54.152.108.131/iphone111/getLearningStandards");

   try {
    // Locate the NodeList name
    jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("LearningStandards");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
     jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
     
     WorldPopulation worldpop = new WorldPopulation();

     worldpop.setRank(jsonobject.optString("standard_title"));
     worldpop.setCountry(jsonobject.optString("ref_id"));
     worldpop.setPopulation(jsonobject.optString("description"));

Comment: Please add it to the question.

Comment: HI @Atri actually I posted my JSON into JSONviewr adn manually i tried to explain the JSON structure.. so plea let me know How can i fetch data from above mentiond JSON

Comment: Try to add the raw Json and update it in the question instead of getting it from JSONViewr.

Comment: Hi I tried to put my code with questions but ist saying that it looks like your post is mostly code please add some more details

Comment: Hi everyone.. Please see my Updated edition. I posted my Code.. in response I am able to see my every data but I can not fetch data from every JSON Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
// JSON file URL address 
jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://54.152.108.131/iphone111/getLearningStandards");
try {
    ArrayList<WorldPopulation> worldpopArray = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
    ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    // Locate the NodeList name 
    jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("LearningStandards");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
        jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
        jsonobject = jsonobject.getJSONObject("LearningStandards");
        WorldPopulation worldpop = new WorldPopulation();
        worldpop.setRank(jsonobject.optString("standard_title"));
        worldpop.setCountry(jsonobject.optString("ref_id"));
        worldpop.setPopulation(jsonobject.optString("description"));
        worldpopArray.add(worldpop);
        spinnerArray.add(jsonobject.optString("standard_title"));
    }

    //Bind spinnerArray to your Spinner

} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @K Neeraj Lal sir,, I have one more question.. According to this, data, I have two spinner, based on standard_title, i have to displayy all rest data in to other spinner,. will you please help me..

Comment: Thank ou so so mucj neera sir... Thank you so muchh .. There should be two spinner, In first spinner only standard_title should be show.. Based on selection of first spinner,, All other data must be populated into second spinner... , once again Thank you so much

Comment: Hello Neeraj Sir, did you completed that code ? when you will update your answer sir .. I am very new in android and i need your guideline. please help me..

Comment: Please post it as a different question.